# StackOverflowError error on running Grails 2.3.2 or above

Tags: java, linux, grails

After installing Grails 2.3.2 or 2.3.3 and setting up the environment path on linux server, it shows the following error when running command `grails -version`

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

There is no problem for Windows and no problem for version 2.3.1.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

OS: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

java version: 1.7.0_45

Comment: How have you installed grails and what does _"setting up the environment"_ mean?  Did you use [gvm](http://gvmtool.net)?

Comment: I mean setup environment variables like GRAILS_HOME & PATH, try both gvm and without gvm. Neither works. Thanks!